# Delete last N bytes from file

Tags: .net, io

There's a file on disk which can be very large. Is there any way to delete the last N bytes from it without copying the remaining content to another file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about this fragment of C# .NET code?

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("filename");
FileStream fs = fi.Open(FileMode.Open);

long bytesToDelete = 5000;
fs.SetLength (Math.Max(0, fi.Length - bytesToDelete));

fs.Close();
```

Comment: same question but from the beginning of a file ? (first N bytes)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, if you want to add or remove bytes at any position: [Insert, delete space at any place in file without making temporary file copy](http://quazistax.blogspot.com/2010/03/insert-delete-space-at-any-place-in.html)